# how to get all comments with their post title linked to posts table in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Comments Table

```
+----+---------+------+------+--------+-----------+
| id | post_id | name | text | status | timestamp |
+----+---------+------+------+--------+-----------+
|  1 |      52 | user | test |      1 | timestamp |
+----+---------+------+------+--------+-----------+
```

Posts

```
+----+--------+------------------+-----------+
| id | title  |   description    | timestamp |
+----+--------+------------------+-----------+
| 52 | mypost | post description | timestamp |
+----+--------+------------------+-----------+
```

Commnet.php [laravel Model]

```
public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
}
```

Post.php [laravel Model]

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
}
```

I want to List all Comments with Post title.
How can I collect Post title included in comments collection?

I do not want to use DB::table(); I want it to be collected through comment Model. like this `$comments = Comment::all()->post->title;`

Comment: use `$comments = Comment::with('post')->get()`

Comment: i want only title value from post table, how do i achive that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Example 1

Usually a query looks like this([laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)):

```
$comments = Comment::with('post')->all();
```

Using the data like this looks like so:

```
foreach($comments as $comment) {
    $comment->name;
    $comment->text;
    $comment->post->title;
}
```

### Example 2

If you want the output to be 'flat' you can also do something like this([laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#joins)):

```
$comments = Comment::select('comments.*', 'posts.title')->join('posts', 'post.id', 'comments.post_id')->get()
```

This way you can use the data like this:

```
foreach($comments as $comment) {
    $comment->name;
    $comment->text;
    $comment->title;
}
```

### Example 3

After seeing your comment under your answer later, I realized the query you could be looking for:

```
$postTitles = Post::select('title')->whereHas('comments')->get()->pluck('title');
```

This will return a collection of post titles, only the post titles which have comments will be shown.

### Example 4

Based on your latest comments I can show you how to filter on comments in post([laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)):

```
 $post = Post
        ::with([
            'category',
            'comments' => function($query) {
                $query->where('status_id', 1);
            },
            'user'
        ])
        -where('slug', $slug)
        ->first();
```

Now you get the first post related to the slug and with it all user details, all category details, but only the comments which have `status_id` 1

Comment: how do I same with a single query?

Comment: @ANOLGHOSH Can you elaborate? 2nd example is a single query, and the first one will result in 2 queries behind the scenes, but will still be efficient. Do you want a list of post titles only? Because then the querie could be different.

Comment: `$comment = Comment::with('post')->findorFail($id);`
this is for quering single comment; this is working.
and all of you example are correct thanks.
But i would like to know .
 how do i add where status = 1 in this `$comments = Post::find($post->id)->comments;` query?

Comment: ahh thats a clear request :) Let me update with example 4 is the status on the post or on the comment?

Comment: `$comments = Post::find($post->id)->comments->where('status',1);` this works but this not usable as `$post = Post::with('category', 'comments', 'user')->where('slug', $slug)->first();` this query gets all comments realated to the post. but in `$post` i cant filter status.

Comment: I added example 4, but we are getting off-track with your original question. Maybe you need to update your question so it is more clear what you are asking.